# Process.Start opens link instead of folder

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, process

I have two items in a parent folder:

1. `example` - a folder.
2. `example.lnk` - a link to a Word document.

<sub>(the .lnk extension is hidden in Windows Explorer even though I have extensions shown).</sub>

When I execute:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\users\user1\theFolder\example");
```

The document is opened.

How do I make it open the folder?

Comment: what do you want it to do instead?

Comment: @DaveBecker Open the folder (in Windows Explorer). Which is what I would expect it to do because it's not `example.lnk` that I'm inputting as the argument.

Comment: I just checked; it opens folder in my case

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Are you sure the names are exactly the same? This is very strange. (I'm running Windows 7 x64 here. Perhaps that makes a difference.)

Comment: Win7x64 here too. I had the same problem. it's weird, I think there must be a bug somewhere (OS/.Net)

Comment: @ispiro I've added the `.lnk` to the shortcut file and that made the difference. Otherwise it opens the link only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"C:\users\user1\theFolder\example");
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. But I wonder why I have to do this. The original version _should_ work.

Comment: You are right, I have no idea how it works, but it does, I just had the same problem, and this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly indicate its a directory:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\users\user1\theFolder\example\");
```

Comment: Thanks. But it didn't help.